# MySQL database taking too much space in ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I need help with the problem of the MySQL database taking too much space, the database size is only a maximum of 1GB but the 77GB **/var/lib/mysql**. How can I resolve this error?
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Since you state MySql I removed the SqlServer tag since it's a completely different product.

Comment: I apologize for the mistake, Thank you for the correction. Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: I found your question because of the SqlServer, not MySql tag - hence why tagging correctly is important.

Comment: You are right, Thank you, I'll remember next time.

Comment: @SonjaySarker The value displayed 77708148 is 77,708,148 which is 77 MB rather than GB.  This is the total space used for the storage, including any sub folders of /var/lib/mysql.  View profile for contact info, please.

Answer (score 3):

With help of `du -Shx /var/lib/mysql | sort -k1 -h | tail -20` you should be able to check which database or folder is responsible for that.

Just a guess in the wild, the storage can be used by binlogs. In that case you can clean them with running the sql query `PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2023-02-01 00:00:00';`.

If the problem is caused by a database, just check the tables and clean them up. This is highly depending on your data. Maybe you can use something like phpMyAdmin or TablePlus to check through the db with a gui.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your quick help, This is the current stage, I have only one database the name is main_web, and its size is 896M, But the /var/lib/mysql directory used 75GB

36K     /var/lib/mysql/mysql
116K    /var/lib/mysql/sys
804K    /var/lib/mysql/#innodb_temp
1.7M    /var/lib/mysql/performance_schema
101M    /var/lib/mysql/#innodb_redo
896M    /var/lib/mysql/main_web
75G     /var/lib/mysql

Comment: You have to check why the db is that big. As mentioned you can download a GUI to connect to the database and find the root cause of the problem. Thats not really a problem we can solve at stackoverflow for you.